# Issue while inputting data into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a hard time inputting simple data into a postgres table.

Here's the table:

```
user=# \d main_attribute_types;

   Column   |         Type          |                             Modifiers                             
------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer               | not null default nextval('main_attribute_types_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying(16) | not null
 field_name | character varying(16) | not null
Indexes:
    "main_attribute_types_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "main_additional_attributes" CONSTRAINT "main_addi_attribute_type_id_1cb89d3d_fk_main_attribute_types_id" FOREIGN KEY (attribute_type_id) REFERENCES main_attribute_types(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

The commands I tried:

```
INSERT INTO main_attribute_types (NULL, "Integer", "IntegerField");
INSERT INTO main_attribute_types (1, "Integer", "IntegerField);
INSERT INTO main_attribute_types (id, name, field_name) VALUES (NULL, "Integer", "IntegerField");
INSERT INTO main_attribute_types (name, field_name) VALUES ("Integer", "IntegerField");
```

And each time I get an error:

```
ERROR:  column "Integer" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO main_attribute_types VALUES (1, "Integer", "Inte...
                                                    ^
```

That's excatly how to do it in official documentation on:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/dml-insert.html

My Postgres version is 9.3.13

I have absolutely no idea why is it not working.

Comment: Strings need to be in single quotes, not double. Just like in the documentation.

Comment: No it's **not** like in the documentation. The documentation uses single quote, not double quotes. `INSERT INTO main_attribute_types (NULL, 'Integer', 'IntegerField');`

Comment: OMG. I feel dumb now.

Comment: In MySQL there is no difference, so I never bothered to check it with the other one. Thank you, it works now.

Comment: The single quote is the one defined by the SQL standard 30 years ago - but MySQL chose to ignore that (and many other things from the SQL standard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO main_attribute_types (name, field_name) VALUES ('Integer', 'IntegerField');
```

remember that the not null is define not null for every column.